# What is the CouchDB equivalent of the SQL COUNT(*) aggregate function?

Tags: couchdb

Yep, I'm a SQL jockey (sorta) coming into the CouchDb Map/Reduce world. I thought I had figured out how the equivalent of the COUNT(*) SQL aggregator function for CouchDB datasets with the following:

Map:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.name, doc);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
  return values.length;
}
```

Which I thought worked, returning something like:

```
"super fun C"   2
"super fun D"   2
"super fun E"   2
"super fun F"   18
```

... but not really. When I add a record, this count varies wildly. Sometimes the count actually *decreases*, which was very surprising. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe I don't fully understand the concept of eventual consistency?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like your reduce results are being re-reduced. That is, `reduce` is called more than once for each key and then called again with those results. You can handle that with a `reduce` function like this:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  if (rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the `map` function so that the values are always a count of documents:

```
// map
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.name, 1);
}

// reduce
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

Comment: Using javascript reduce functions instead of the built in ones will give you very bad performance.  See David's answer

Answer (score 44):

In your reduce just put:

_count

You can also get a sum using:

_sum

so basically reduce: "_sum" or reduce: "_count" and make sure the value your map emits is a valid integer (numeric value)

See ["Built in reduce functions"](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/maintenance/performance.html#built-in-reduce-functions).

Comment: This is the better answer. Read the link David posted here about built-in functions.