# Accessing Cloudant database with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to connect to my CouchDB on Cloudant using `jQuery` and `jQuery.couch.sj`

However, I can't even get the most basic info about my database. For example the following code prints nothing to the console.

**Code**

```
<script>
$.couch.urlPrefix ="https://acharya.cloudant.com";
$.couch.info({
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
});
</script>
```

I've [looked](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.db.html#.getDbProperty) at [the](http://java.dzone.com/news/couchdb-jquery-plugin) [online](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/) [documentation](http://examples.cloudant.com/simplegeo_places/_design/geo/index.html#complex) but to no avail.

If I type

```
var db= $.couch.db("toxtweet");
console.debug(db);
```

to see something about one of my CouchDB's, I get:

```
Object { name="toxtweet",uri="https://acharya.cloudant.com/toxtweet/", compact=function(), 
more...}
```

And that is the correct URI. So, how would I, for example, get the number of documents in the "toxtweet" database? Trying the example doesn't work.

**Update**
If I view the page in Chrome instead of Firefox I see the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://acharya.cloudant.com/. Origin http://tox.sinaiem.org is not  
allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I thought that Cloudant was a CouchApp that bypassed the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used jquery to access Cloudant, but I would expect you to have to log in somewhere first unless you have somehow made your database public.

Have you checked in Chrome or Firefox what https requests and responses jquery.couch is sending and receiving?

To get the number of documents, you would typically have a view with a reduce method like this:

```
// map
function(doc) {
 emit(doc.id, 1);
}

// reduce
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

see here for more info [What is the CouchDB equivalent of the SQL COUNT(*) aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586585/what-is-the-couchdb-equivalent-of-the-sql-count-aggregate-function)

I would recommend you use Futon when trying out examples before doing an equivalent request in jquery.couch

**Update**

Have you tried JSONP to get around cross domain issue?
see here: http://support.cloudant.com/customer/portal/articles/359321-how-do-i-read-and-write-to-my-cloudant-database-from-the-browser-

Comment: I made the database publicly visible for testing purposes.

Comment: Well, I'd like to write to the documents from a webpage. Also, the following link made me think that the JSONP workaround was outdated. https://cloudant.com/blog/make-it-easy/

Comment: JSONP is just one of the workarounds. In the link you posted and example at the bottom, he comments that he's set up an apache reverse proxy which is another way to get around the cross domain issue.

Comment: Personally I don't like the idea of opening my database to everyone. I also don't think it's good design to couple your UI to your data.

However, for some scenario's it makes sense. It's up to you to decide what's best and what you're most comfortable with.

I love node.js so would recommend https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
If you have to set up a reverse proxy anyway, you might as well serve up your whole site from your server and create your own REST api and call that from your client.

Answer (score 1):

CouchApp's/Cloudant don't bypass same origin policy. If you have a CouchApp on Cloudant you can access it under your domain (e.g. https://acharya.cloudant.com/DB_NAME/_design/DESIGN/index.html), if you want that on another domain you'll need a reverse proxy as AndyD suggests.

The CouchDB wiki has two nice run throughs for using [HTTPD](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Apache_As_a_Reverse_Proxy) or [Nginx](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Nginx_As_a_Reverse_Proxy) as a reverse proxy, both should apply when running against a database hosted in Cloudant.

HTH

Simon