# CouchDB 2.0+ count all documents with a certain field value

Tags: database, performance, couchdb, document-database

I'm new to CouchDB and I'm looking for the best way to perform the following count:

I've got documents that look like this:

```
{
field_1: "some_string",
field_2: "some_other_string"
}
```

I want to count all documents that have a certain value in `field_2`, so that I know what´s the `limit` I should set when finding all documents with that field value via `POST /{db}/_find` using a `selector`.

I've read some things about Design Documents and Views and Query Protocol, but I can't understand what's the proper way of achieving this. Do I even need to count first the number of documents? Or is there a way to quickly know this when performing the lookup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the CouchDB equivalent of the SQL COUNT(\*) aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586585/what-is-the-couchdb-equivalent-of-the-sql-count-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

> ... when finding all documents with that field value ...

I assume your **purpose** is to find all docs with a specific field having a certain value.

I don't know much about CouchDB *mango* queries with `/<db>/_find` or `/<db>/_index`, but I think you can find all docs with a specific field value by just doing HTTP requests.

---

Assume you have documents like below, and you want to find all docs with `title` field equal to `Jacob` string:

```
{
  "_id": "doc5",
  "_rev": "1-27f5da5ca3157d4bca8b485d411e86c5",
  "unicodeString": "יעקב",
  "title": "Jacob"
}
```

You can implement a view map function like below. This view, sorts all docs inside the database according to the `title` field in a B-tree data structure:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.title){
    emit(doc.title, [doc.unicodeString])
  }
}
```

Lets assume the name of the above view is `by_title` and the name of database is `sample`, then we can do a HTTP request like below to get all the docs with the `title` field equal to, for example, `Jacob` string:

```
$ curl -k -X GET https://joe:joe@192.168.1.106:6984/sample/_design/by_title/_view/by_title?key=\"Jacob\"
{"total_rows":15,"offset":8,"rows":[
{"id":"doc5","key":"Jacob","value":["יעקב"]},
{"id":"doc6","key":"Jacob","value":["ישראל"]}
]}
```

As you see the above HTTP GET request with `curl` returns all the docs with the `title` field equal to `Jacob` string. I'm using `https` along with `6984` port, since I'm using CouchDB with SLL and self-signed certificate, but you can use it with `http` and port `5984`.

Also in the above `curl` command i'm using my key with escaped double-quotes like this: `?key=\"Jacob\"`. The reason for this is that my Linux shell command line eats the double-quotes before passing them to `curl`, therefore I have to escape them to make it work.