# How to count number of record filtered by selector

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm making smart contract with Go and I want to use Rich Query to get total count of records from CouchDB filtered by some selector like:

`{\"selector\":{\"doc_type\": \"person\"}}`

It is similar to:

`select count(*) from tb where ...`

as SQL query but how to do it with CouchDB?

Comment: What problem do you have? Is that query not working?

Comment: In CouchDB, it doesn't support aggregation queries. So I have to implement it via chaincode by looping and counting each record one by one. My question is there any way to do so with faster performance?

Comment: "In CouchDB, it doesn't support aggregation queries" sure it does. That's the whole point of [reduce functions](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/intro.html#reduce-rereduce).

Comment: So if I want to count I have to loop and count manually right? If I have more than 10K records, will it slow down my query? The method I used is `GetQueryResultWithPagination`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the CouchDB equivalent of the SQL COUNT(\*) aggregate function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586585/what-is-the-couchdb-equivalent-of-the-sql-count-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to perform a rich query in chaincode then all you can do is iterate over the results and count each one. Also note that hyperledger fabric bounds the total number records you can query (it's a configuration parameter) so that would also be another consideration. 
I would recommend reading this section https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/couchdb_as_state_database.html#good-practices-for-queries
as it sounds like what you are trying to perform is likely to be not very performant

Comment: YES, I am now using this method to get total record count. I used `GetQueryResultWithPagination` to query all records as pages and count. I'm looking for alternative way with better performance.

Comment: There isn't any other way currently from chaincode. The link I provided provides suggestions from client side as an example.